# underscore - convert complex object into array using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to format my object array into an array to be used by a component. I need to map the exact values of the object to the correct positions.

e.g.

My Raw Data:

```
var rawData = [
                { name: 'john',
                  age: 23,
                  style : 'expert',
                  max : 'none'
                },
                { name: 'mick',
                  age: 36,
                  style : 'inter',
                  max : 'none'
                },
                { name: 'pete',
                  age: 44,
                  style : 'med',
                  max : 'none'
                }
               ]
```

i would like to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) to convert this object to the following array format so I can use in my component which requires this format.

Please note only `name` `age` and `style` are required not `max`. I have more undesired properties but for example above I did not want to write all.

```
var result = [
   [ "john", "23", "expoert"],
   [ "mick", "36", "inter"],
   [ "pete", "44", "med"]
]
```

I have tried `pluck` and `map` combinations, but can't seem to get the order correct in the outputted array. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to use underscore.js?

Comment: Well that is the lib I use now. But happy if solution can be done without. I only want certain values to be mapped and not all. e.g. name, age and style, but not max or any other props which may be in my object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
const rawData = [
     { name: 'john', age: 23, style : 'expert' },
     { name: 'mick', age: 36, style : 'inter' }
];

const result = rawData.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

Theres no need to use a library at all. Or more explicitly:

```js
    const rawData = [
         { name: 'john', age: 23, style : 'expert' },
         { name: 'mick', age: 36, style : 'inter' }
    ];

    const result = rawData.map(({name, age, style}) => [name, age, style]);

    console.log(result);
```

I would prefer this as object key/value order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial without any library using [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
var rawData = [{
  name: 'john',
  age: 23,
  style: 'expert'
}, {
  name: 'mick',
  age: 36,
  style: 'inter'
}, {
  name: 'pete',
  age: 44,
  style: 'med'
}]

var res = rawData.map(o=>Object.values(o))
console.log(res)
```